# Connecting to AWS RDS database from a non-AWS hosting server

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

I am hosting my Django (2.1) app on Namecheap shared hosting and I need to connect the app to my AWS RDS Postgresql database. I can connect to the database from my local pgAdmin4 and local Django app, but my app hosted on Namecheap cannot connect. I get this error:

> could not connect to server: Connection refused   Is the server running
>   on host "hcdatabase.cvikoyffier8.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
>   (3.209.46.205) and accepting  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Here are my settings for the RDS database:

Port: 5432

Public Accessibility: Yes

Security Group Rules: Inbound Allow All TCP (Port 0-65535) from Anywhere

Subnet Group: default-vpc-0c3bc057b4c1135da

I think I might have to change the Subnets to something accessible from outside of AWS but I have no idea how to do it. Any idea??

Comment: Just ran this command , and telnet accepted the connection. "telnet hcdatabase.cvikoyffier8.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com 5432". This means your security groups' settings are fine

Comment: Security group misconfiguration will *never* result in `Connection refused` and a healthy RDS instance will also never return this error, which is an active reset of the connection attempt by *something*.  Security groups reject disallowed traffic passively, not actively, resulting instead in `Connection timed out`.  The most likely explanation is that the network of the other "shared hosting" provider is blocking the connection, outbound.

Comment: Side-note: It is always best to have your application and database _as close as possible_ to have low-latency. Hosting them on separate services will likely impact the speed of your queries.